# Where to find Magento Configuration files

Tags: magento2.3, phtml

[image]I'm trying to change a default setting in Magento, and I have found the solution how to change it.

The issue is I can't find the file, I need to modify `items.phtml`.

The path is **`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/items.phtml`**. But I think the post was for Magento 1, I'm not 100% sure.

Where I can find the **`items.phtml`** file?

I am trying to set the Email Copy of Shipment as "Checked" as default. Please see the attached screenshot.

I found an old post where a person wanted to achieve the same and was provided this ( I found out later that the post was 9 years old):

__('Email Copy of Shipment') ?>

When created the "items.phtml" and did what was suggested in the comments nothing changed.

I did run after i inserted the file. : php bin/magento setup:upgrade and deploy, Cleared cache and re indexed.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: So items.phtml overrides adminhtml right?

Comment: You can FInd this file in /vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/view/items.phtml
or also you can create a new file in app/design/adminhtml/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Shipping/templates/order/view/items.phtml

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for the help,

When i go to app/design/adminhtml//vendor/ - there is no directories beyond this point, I tried to do ls -la and also ls /ld to see if there is any hidden.

Comment: Hi @Jan-petterHavna you need to create app/design/adminhtml/{your_custom_vendor}/{your_custom_theme}/Magento_Shipping/templates/order/view/items.phtml (This is if it overrides adminhtm, if it overrides frontend then it will be frontend instead of adminhtml )

Comment: @zarnParekh 

I did this, and nothing changes, I'm trying to set Email Copy of Shipment as selected as default. so when we push send we don't need to check this box every time.

the code i was provided was this: <p>
    <label class="normal" for="send_email"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email Copy of Shipment') ?></label>
    <input id="send_email" name="shipment[send_email]" value="1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
</p>

Comment: @rahulChittora What will the path be when in /app when i found the item.phtml file on this path? :
vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/create/items.phtm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be over thinking the file location.
Go to the folder where magento is installed.
then go to:
/vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/view/items.phtml
Make your change there
Then just refresh your web browser.

Comment: HI, 
Thank you for your answer. 

Is this for the admin panel? not the website it self. I found the file, and if this sis the case I do have been overthinking. 

However, i can not fine the line of code with Checkbox's inside this file. Can i add the code i have received inside there? Or am i on the wrong file?

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is resolved now!

Comment: I found the path and did the change in item.phtml, but i have a feeling that is safer to do this if I do it like they mention above to create custom folders etc in app//design/adminhtml: But what will the pat be there if i found it here:vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/create/items.phtm